# Global options on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am new to nodejs, mongodb and started a project using meteor. Everything went really fine so far.

Imagine I want to create a website for managing accomodations and their booking requests. Setting up the accomodations was really easy.. now I have global options like setting time periods for "high season", "low season", "mid season"... or texts that are common for each accomodation.

Normally I'd just write that down in my accomodation template but the reason I want to save this in MongoDb is that I want the website admin to be able to edit those contents.

Where do I store those "global settings"? Where do I store texts that belong to every accomodation?

For now I've created a collection named "options" and created a document named "accomodations" that holds the different seasons and messages.. but that feels like a bad work around.

Hope you understand!

Comment: I also thought about creating a new collection for "seasons" or for "messages".. is that a good idea?

Comment: One could argue that configuration settings which are few and change very rarely should not be stored in a database but rather in a configuration file on the application server. But arguing is not what this website is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to have an "options" collection to store site-wide settings.

```
{
  someOption: true,
  anotherOption: 8500
}
```

I'd recommend the [Astronomy](https://atmospherejs.com/jagi/astronomy) package to help define your data structure.

If you edit your answer to better explain various your various data and how it relates to each other, I can edit my answer to give more details or suggest how I'd structure it myself.

Comment: I was using Collection2 which doesnt support relations for now. Do you recommend astronomy over collection2?

Comment: Astronomy is more of an ORM/schema design package, collection2 is (if I'm not mistaken) for validating inserts/updates/etc. I'm not terribly familiar with collection2. But, even the author of simple-schema recommends Astronomy over his solution. :)

Comment: Sadly SimpleSchema has a lot more integrations .. Autoform, Collection2, orionjs..

Answer (score 0):

Organizing a MongoDB database structure with relations is tricky if you want to utilize MongoDB for its strengths.

Creating a related collection that can then be referenced by the others is the only way to share a record between multiple collections. The main way MongoDB would ideally handle relations is by embedding a document but then you lose the ability for it to be referenced by other documents.

If this is the only case where you are feeling this strain with MongoDB then a external reference isn't horrible. Libraries like mongoose help you manage schemas and relations. If however you're finding yourself relying on this pattern heavily it's possible a traditional SQL database would suit you better.